# Carbon equivalent of NSTask?

Tags: c++, macos, shell, boost, macos-carbon

OS X 10.6.8, Carbon, C++ app.

I want to run a command from a shell and get back the result as a string to then use as a parameter to another function.

`df / | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }'`

But I dont see an NSTask equivalent for Carbon, C++ and as far as I can find I would need to use Objective-C to use NSTask

I dont see that Boost has anything to offer either.

Can anyone point me in a right direction?

EDIT: So trying to remember my UNIX days, what about using `popen` in read mode and getting the results I want from the file pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can write something like this:

```
int myPipe[2];
int err = pipe(&myPipe); // write to myPipe[1] in child, read from myPipe[0] in parent

int child_pid = fork();
if(child_pid == 0)
{
    err = dup2(myPipe[1], 1); // redirect standard output to the input of the pipe
    execl("/path/to/program", "arg1", "arg2");
}

int pipefd = myPipe[0];
char buffer[255];
err = read(pipefd, buffer, 255);
```

Don't forget to add some checks and wait for the child process.

But if you can use Cocoa, but don't know how to join C++ and Objective-C code - just use Objective-C++ placing code to the file with .mm extension.